# React-Native Failed to build DependencyGraph: Watchman error

Tags: android, react-native, watchman

I getting this error when I want to run my project on Android emulator.

```
[Hot Module Replacement] Server listening on /hot

React packager ready.

Failed to build DependencyGraph: Watchman error: query failed: synchronization failed: Permission denied. Make sure watchman is running for this project. See https://facebook.github.io/watchman/docs/troubleshooting.html.
Error: Watchman error: query failed: synchronization failed: Permission denied. Make sure watchman is running for this project. See https://facebook.github.io/watchman/docs/troubleshooting.html.
    at /Users/Ali/Desktop/app/Test/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/node-haste/lib/crawlers/watchman.js:63:11
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:368:9)
```

I tried "watchman watch ~path" , "sudo" & "chmod" but they didn't help me.

Can someone advise me please?

Comment: This may help you https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/2564

Comment: I used that but it didn't work.

Comment: Hey.. Got any solution?

Comment: Not until now. But try this one , it maybe helps you. http://stackoverflow.com/a/37402017/6366574

Comment: I had the same problem and rebooting the laptop fixed it for me.

Answer (score 10):

solved by reinstalling watchman

```
brew update
brew reinstall watchman
```

Answer (score 2):

cd AwesomeProject, and execute `chmod -R 777 *` it still failed.
after i give the permission to the top dir, it work!
`chmod 777 AwesomeProject`

Comment: Recursively changing the owner of the relevant directory (whatever is referenced in the error) fixed it in my case.  But before I tried that, I tried 777 perms, and that worked to.  But 755 was liberal enough once I fixed the owner.

Answer (score 2):

check pid and kill

```
lsof -n -i4TCP:8081 | grep LISTEN
```

run this command with root

```
react-native start
```

Answer (score 1):

I've tried all the above and none of the solutions worked, try this:

type `watchman watch ./`

in the top directory of the RN project you want to run,

then again `react-native run-ios`

Answer (score 0):

check pid

```
lsof -n -i4TCP:8081 | grep LISTEN
```

and kill pid

run with root

```
react-native start
```